# iptables port forwarding for my game server

Tags: centos, iptables, port-forwarding

I have an 2 dedicated server and I want port forwarding (game - Minecraft) but I can't forward porting to destination server.

TCP PORT : 25565

UDP PORTS : 19132,19133,25565

I already have tried this code block:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -X

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25565 -j DNAT --to-destination server2:25565
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -d server1 --match multiport --dport 19132,19133,25565 -j SNAT --to-source server2
```

Comment: What error message(s) are you getting?

Comment: Can you clarify, whether your two servers have public IPs and why do you need port forwarding between them? Port forwarding is a terrible hack, it will drain `server1`'s connection.

Comment: to remove any ambiguity, could you add in your question the output of all this (run from both servers): `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route; iptables-save -c`. Feel free to obfuscate, but please use [RFC 5737](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5737) addresses then.

Comment: `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route; iptables-save -c` its not working :( my skype adress : live:.cid.6cc4a2ce8e420f3b anyone can help me?

Comment: Let us [continue the discussion in the chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102806/discussion-on-question-iptables-port-forwarding-for-my-game-server).